# How to use an unlisted CTAN mirror URL in MikTeX?

Tags: miktex, ctan

Is there any way to manually enter the URL of a CTAN mirror in MikTeX, if  that URL is *not* part of the official repository list? Unfortunately company guidelines won't allow me to run an official mirror, but I have a large number of new users every few months downloading the complete repository, so I'd like to save some bandwidth and time by providing the packages in the local network.

Comment: You can create local repositories by downloading the miktex/tm/packages folder from CTAN to some local folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MiKTeX offers an installation program on the MiKTeX homepage.  It is important to use this program (basic or net version) to install MiKTeX.

You need two runs of the installer programm:

1. To download all needed files for the installation. All theese files were downloaded to a special directory you can change. (**That is the point you can work with!**)
2. To install all downloaded files in the **given** directory.

Image of the step where you can change/create the diirectory for the downloaded files (first red arrow: Username of downloading user, second red arrow: Setup directory!):

[image]

Now just prepare an directory for example `z:\MiKTeX2.9Setup` in your local network, download the needed files (I suggest to use the complete installation).

Now all is prepared and you can advice your students to install MiKTeX ommitting the first step (because the download is already done, you did it!). They have to start the MiKteX installer program and follow it. If they reach the following window

[image]

They have to click on install and add later the directory name you prepared.  That's it.

Of course then it is your job (or for a script) to keep this directory up to date!

At home students have to follow the complete procedure (first downloading, second installing) to install MiKTeX on the private computer.

Comment: Although this is not what I originally intended to do, this seems to be a more sensible solution. Thanks!

Comment: It's just a bummer that installing from a network directory requires the directory to be mounted as a network drive.